# Why is it true that $\frac{1}{t}\ln\left\{ 1+ t\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\ln x_k + O(t^2) \right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n p_k\ln x_k + O(t)$ as $t\to 0$?

Tags: calculus

(*The Cauchy-Schwarz Master class* by Michael Steele, page 121) It is given that $\ln(1+x) = x+O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$. Then, as $t\to 0$ one has

$$\frac{1}{t}\ln\left\{ 1+ t\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\ln x_k + O(t^2) \right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n p_k\ln x_k + O(t)$$
This is a step in a book that I'm reading. $O(t^2)$ and $O(t)$ use the [big $O$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Why does the equality hold?

Comment: Just prove $\frac{1}{t}\ln(1+at+O(t^2)) = a+O(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When  considering the condition $t\to 0$ we can write the series expansion of $\ln t$ as
\begin{align*}
\ln(1+t)&=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\cdots\\
&=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+O(t^3)\\
&=t+O(t^2)\tag{1}\\
&=O(t)
\end{align*}

We use the Big-O notation corresponding to the accuracy we need for our calculation. In the current situation when setting $a=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\ln x_k$ we see the right-hand side of
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{t}\ln\left( 1+ at + O(t^2) \right) =a + O(t)
\end{align*}
represents the constant term exactly while the linear part  and all higher powers of $t$ are swallowed by $O(t)$.

> We obtain according to (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{t}}&\color{blue}{\ln(1+at+O(t^2))}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}\left[(at+O(t^2))+O((at+O(t^2))^2)\right]\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}\left[(at+O(t^2))+O(a^2t^2+2atO(t^2)+O(t^2)O(t^2))\right]\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}\left[at+O(t^2)+O(a^2t^2+O(t^3)+O(t^4))\right]\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}\left[at+O(t^2)+O(t^2)+O(t^3)+O(t^4)\right]\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{t}\left[at+O(t^2))\right]\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=a+O(t)}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Depending  on  the level of experience some of the intermediate steps will usually be skipped.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use for constant $a$ the rule $aO(t)=O(t)$ as well as the rules $t=O(t)$, $O(t)O(t)=O(t^2)$ and $O(t^2)O(t^2)=O(t^4)$.
- In (3) we use the rule $O(O(t^k))=O(t^k)$.
- In (4) we use $O(t^4)=O(t^3)$ and  $O(t^3)=O(t^2)$ as well as $O(t^2)+O(t^2)=O(t^2)$.
- In  (5) we  use $\frac{1}{t}O(t^2)=O(t)$.

**Note:** The rules stated in the comment section can be derived for instance from formulas (9.21) - (9.27) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.